# Cannot open a new Microsoft Word document in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ms-word, applescript

I have a task to open Microsoft Word and create a new document in Objective C.

If I am running an Apple Script below in the Script Editor, it works fine and a new Microsoft Word document gets created:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word" to make new document
```

BUT, if I am trying to call the same script from Objective-C code (see it below), it only opens the Microsoft Word application, but does not create a new document :

```
NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleScript * appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:

@"tell application \"Microsoft Word\" to make new document"];

[appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
```

I guess there is something to do with the permissions.

Any ideas are very welcome!

Comment: Have you added a `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` field to your `Info.plist`?

Comment: Does not seem to make ny difference. Do I need to set a value for the key?
Please, have a look how my Info.plist looks like here - https://a.uguu.se/XYdQdoEqsV4s_InfoPList_AppleEventsSelected.png . Is it correct?

Comment: It is strange that it works partly. It does start Microsoft Word, which means it has some permissions, but it does not create a new document.
You can download and see my test project here - http://www.studioerudit.com/share/VSOTestCocoa2.zip
MacOS: Catalina 10.15.1
XCode: v. 10.2.1 (10E1001)
Language: Objective-C

Comment: “Is it correct?” Looks okay. Have you also checked your project’s [sandboxing/hardening settings](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125703#thread-post-393709)? Be aware that process launching is not done via Apple events but by a separate system call, so won’t be affected by a sandbox rule that blocks outgoing AEs.

Comment: Anything useful in `errorDict` ?